# Replace element from first array by another element of second array

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am having this issue replacing element from first array by another element of second array.

For exapmle if I have one array haiving some empty values and string like this:

```
let array_1 = [empty, 'Connected', empty, 'Connected', 'Connected'];
```

And another new array will be like this:

```
let array_2 = [empty, 'Updated'];
```

So, New updated array with replaced element will look like this:

```
newArray = [empty, 'Updated', empty, 'Connected', 'Connected'];
```

I tried with for loop and by using findIndexof, but could not replace the element with exact index address.

One of them which worked for me partially is:

```
console.log(Object.values(...array_1, ...array_2));
```

Out of above line is just one array with one element, not reast of element from `array_1`:

```
['Updated']
```

But it seems like `Obejct.values()` does not work with element generated as a `empty`.

Any possible solution on this would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood it properly you can solve it by using map function like this:

```js
let array_1 = [undefined, "Connected", undefined, "Connected", "Connected"];
let array_2 = [undefined, "Updated"];

const res = array_1.map((val, idx) => {
  return array_2[idx] || val;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Could you explain it in brief?  that would be nice. And tell how empty element from the array behaves like?

Comment: Yeah sure, and empty element in a javascript array is always assigned as undefined, And this map loops the array one and returns or the values of the same position of the array 2 or if the array 2 has no values for this position return the val of the first array

Comment: Execellent! But when I checked with `console.log(typeof array2[0])` it showed me `undefined`, but in for loop or map function it did't show me anything. why?